# Deadlock with recursive, concurrent code using go-routines

Tags: recursion, go, concurrency, deadlock

I'm trying to implement a generic search algorithm that will traverse any arbitrary tree-like data structure concurrently (spinning up a go routine for each level of the tree).

The issue I have is when search fails (it completes walking the entire tree and finds no match) I end up with a deadlock and I don't understand why.

The code works when correctly when search succeeds.

I added the helper functions for your context, however my issue is with the way I'm using go-routines and channels which is all in the concurrentSearch() function.

I apoligize in advance if you find the code messy. I've been going back and forth all day trying out different ideas.

Thanks for any feedback!

Here's my code:

```
package search

import "reflect"

// Search an arbitrary tree / map like data structure.
func concurrentSearch(output chan interface{}, data interface{}, key string) {
    // search() is your search algorithm.
    result := search(data, key)
    if result != nil {
        // Found something, so put it on the chan.
        // This is the point of the function.
        output <- result
        return // Success.
    }

    // Since we didn't find a match we will get a slice of the next level of values.
    iterableType := listValues(data)
    if len(iterableType) == 0 {
        return
    }

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for _, value := range iterableType {
        wg.Add(1)

        go func(next interface{}) {
            defer wg.Done()
            concurrentSearch(output, next, key)
        }(value)

    }
    wg.Wait()
    // Wait never finishes, so the function never returns
} 

// Returns a slice of values based on Type.
func listValues(data interface{}) []interface{} {
    value := reflect.ValueOf(data)
    values := []interface{}{}

    switch value.Kind() {
    case reflect.Map:
        for _, key := range value.MapKeys() {
            values = append(values, value.MapIndex(key).Interface())
        }

    case reflect.Slice:
        for ii := 0; ii < value.Len(); ii++ {
            values = append(values, value.Index(ii).Interface())
        }

    case reflect.Struct:
        for ii := 0; ii < value.NumField(); ii++ {
            if value.Field(ii).CanSet() {
                values = append(values, value.Field(ii).Interface())
            }
        }

    case reflect.Ptr:
        rawValue := value.Elem()
        if !rawValue.IsValid() {
            return nil
        }
        values = listValues(rawValue)

    case reflect.Interface:
        rawValue := value.Elem()
        values = listValues(rawValue)
    }

    return values
}

// search just checks the value for an index of key, otherwise returns nil.
func search(data interface{}, key string) interface{} {
    value := reflect.ValueOf(data)
    switch value.Kind() {

    // If the type is indexable, check the index.
    // Default to returning nil
    case reflect.Struct:
        for ii := 0; ii < value.NumField(); ii++ {
            field := value.Field(ii)
            // Without CanSet() reflect panics about Unexported fields.
            if field.CanSet() {
                if field.Type().Name() == key {
                    return field.Elem().Interface()
                }
            }
        }
        return nil

    case reflect.Map:
        for _, mapkey := range value.MapKeys() {
            if key == mapkey.String() {
                return value.MapIndex(mapkey).Elem().Interface()
            }
        }
        return nil

    case reflect.Slice:
        return nil

        // For pointer types we just unwrap and call again.
    case reflect.Ptr:
        rawValue := value.Elem()
        if !rawValue.IsValid() {
            return nil
        }
        return search(rawValue, key)

    case reflect.Interface:
        rawValue := value.Elem()
        return search(rawValue, key)

    case reflect.String:
        return nil

    default:
        return nil
    }

}
```

Here's my test code, unfortunately I can't share the test data. It's just a bunch of nested json objects.

```
package state

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "reflect"
    "testing"
)

const (
    dataPath = "path/to/your/data.json"
)

var tests = []struct {
    Input  string
    Result interface{}
}{
    // your test fixtures here for table driven tests.
}

type mydata struct {
    One   map[string]interface{} `json:"1"`
    Two   map[string]interface{} `json:"2"`
    Three map[string]interface{} `json:"3"`
}

func TestConcurrentSearch(t *testing.T) {
    data := &mydata{
        map[string]interface{}{},
        map[string]interface{}{},
        map[string]interface{}{},
    }
    bytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(dataPath)
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("ioutil: problem loading test data, %v", err)
    }
    jerr := json.Unmarshal(bytes, data)
    if jerr != nil {
        t.Errorf("json: problem unmarshalling test data, %s", jerr)
    }

    // Setup finished

    output := make(chan interface{})
    for _, fixture := range tests {
        go concurrentSearch(output, data, fixture.Input)
        select {
        case result := <-output:
            if !reflect.DeepEqual(fixture.Result, result) {
                t.Errorf("Expected: %v, Actual %v", fixture.Result, result)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The way you wait for go-routines to finish in `concurrentSearch` seems a bit strange (using `done` channel), usually this is done using `WaitGroup`.

Comment: Use a `WaitGroup`. You have paths in your function that can return without sending a value on the channel, so it's possible to have fewer results than inputs.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @ain and @JimB. Updated to use a `WaitGroup`, which was exactly the construct I needed for waiting on go-routines, however the problem remains. I believe the logic in `concurrentSearch` is flawed, any suggestions on how to restructure my code so that I can guarantee the chan gets the proper inputs vs outputs. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You only added a WaitGroup around the recursive call of concurrentSearch. You're still waiting for the same number of outputs as goroutines in the Test function.

Comment: You don't need to do a select with only a single case, just read off the channel normally.  Still, your logic seems sound.  @JimB, he's only waiting for the number of initial calls to concurrentSearch, which is the number of keys being searched for.  The test will hang indefinitely if a key can't be found, of course, because there's no provision for a "not found" case, but he's not waiting on the full list of goroutines in his test.  He's not even waiting for the first one to return (which he could do with a buffered channel and a non-`go` call), he's just waiting for a result for each test.

Comment: Just saying that the code should be structured correctly first (I'd write an answer if I saw the actual problem while skimming the code ;) ). Once the obvious bugs are eliminated, look at a stack trace to see where each goroutine is blocked.